# getchar() while user is writing

Tags: c, timing, getchar

I'm simulating a tv game in a C prompt program. The player has 60 seconds to guess a word, and when he finds it, he has to press enter to get a new one: the word changes, and the number of words and the time left upgrade.
Because the "enter listener" part is a getchar, I was guessing if it could be possible to do a real-time upgrading of the time left second by second, while waiting for the enter pressing with getchar().

```
while(1) {
        system("clear"); //RAND WORD
        parola = parole[rand() % n]; //PRINT WORDS, NEW WORD, SECONDS LEFT
        printf("\n\n[%d]\t\t%s\t\t%d", indovinate, parola, secLeft);

        gettimeofday(&initTime, NULL);
        int initSec = initTime.tv_sec; //WAIT FOR PAYLER TO PRESS ENTER
        getchar();

        gettimeofday(&tookTime, NULL);
        int tookSec = tookTime.tv_sec - initSec; //UPGRADE TIME TOOK
        secLeft -= tookSec;
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But asking for how to do that is a way to broad question.

Comment: This would be much easier to accomplish with a console library like `ncurses` or even `readline`.

Comment: not sure what OS you're on, but a non-blocking syscall like select or poll could be used to check for chars to read and if there aren't any you just update the time and loop

Answer (score 0):

try `kbhit()`,
It's part of the `conio.h` library.
It basically checks if a key is pressed. If it isn't you can update the time. if it is you can input the answer.

```
if(kbhit()){
    a = getch();
}
else{
    //update time
}
```

you might want to use `getch()`, it doesn't need the player to press enter.

There might be better ways to do this than c. (Don't ask me, I don't do stuff like this)

But if It's just a cool project, go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

you can use delay of dos.h with the kbhit() of conio.h
the delay(time) take integer as time to pause the program from execution for that 'time' amount

````
int i=0;
while (i<60||!kbhit())       // wait till i reach value 60 or key is pressed
 {//doing the stuff
  i++;}
if (i==60)
printf("\n sorry but the time out you may try next time");```
````